# React/Enzyme: Mocking/stubbing nested components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, enzyme

I'm using mocha/chai/enzyme/sinon to test my React components.  Suppose I am looking to test the following component, and that I need to `mount` it in order to test lifecycle methods.

```
<Container>
  <div />
  <NestedContainer />
  <div />
</Container>
```

Suppose further that I do **not** want to in any case mount the component `NestedContainer`.  Instead what I would like to do, is mock/stub out `NestedContainer` with a plain old `div` before mounting `Container`.

I've looked for solutions online to do this, and the only relevant resource I've found is this:  https://medium.com/@AndreCalvo/react-component-testing-mocking-method-calls-components-and-time-d780d45e4cd5.  It seems kind of heavy to bring in a large library to mock these components.

Does anyone know of any other way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mount in order to test lifecycle methods.

You can use `instance()`.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);

wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
```

This will trigger the lifecycle method specified.

This is great for testing that redux actions (which can be mocked) are called etc.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.  Either way, I still need to mount the component, as I need to test things beyond lifecycle methods.

Comment: Like what? In my experience, you can get away with testing most things without having to mount.

Comment: I'm using axe-core to test the accessibility of the rendered HTML.

Comment: Ah OK fair enough. Is your app particularly accessibility-focused? Otherwise, you could rely on linting tools to ensure you have what you need. i.e. a11y has an eslint plugin

Comment: Haha, I'm also using a11y typescript linting rules.  In some scenarios a11y does not catch everything, however, which is why we are looking to test the accessibility of the rendered HTML.